# Making sure File-upload is working! max_upload and what else?

Tags: php, file-upload

i wanna make really sure, that a user can upload large files to my server.
which php settings do i have to consider in my php.ini file that make sure a file-upload doesn't fail?

i've now set those tow lines in my php.ini file:

```
upload_max_filesize = 500M ;
post_max_size = 500M ;
```

is there anything else i need to consider?

thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the value of "memory_limit" as well.

[Excerpt from the PHP Doc.](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

> If memory limit is enabled by your configure script, memory_limit also affects file uploading. Generally speaking, memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size.

Comment: And of course, the webserver's limits as well, such as Apache's LimitRequestBody